# rpmbuild issues on CentOS - Bad exit status from /home/me/rpmbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.58942

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I'm trying to create a package that only updates files on the system, but I keep getting errors when rpmbuild is run.  The error indicates a file is missing.

I've tried this on CentOS 5 and 6 with the same results.

I used `rpmdev-setuptree` to setup the file system, which also setup `~/.rpmmacros` file. I then used `rpmdev-newspec` to initialize the spec file.

I am running as a non-root user.

I have the spec file in `~/rpmbuild/SPECS/test.spec` and my source is: `~/rpmbuild/SOURCES/test-1.tar.gz` .  Extracting this file creates a directory named `test-1` with 2 files inside of it. I've confirmed that it does get extracted to `~/rpmbuild/BUILD/test-1` when I try to build the package.

I run: `rpmbuild -ba ~/rpmbuild/SPECS/test.spec`

Then I get this error:

> - ./configure --build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --target=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu --program-prefix= --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --sbindir=/usr/sbin --sysconfdir=/etc --datadir=/usr/share --includedir=/usr/include --libdir=/usr/lib64 --libexecdir=/usr/libexec --localstatedir=/var --sharedstatedir=/usr/com --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info /home/me/rpmbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.58942: line 37: ./configure: No such file or directory error: Bad exit status from
>     /home/me/rpmbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.58942 (%build)
>
> RPM build errors:
>       Bad exit status from /home/me/rpmbuild/tmp/rpm-tmp.58942 (%build)

Here is my spec file:

```
Name:           test
Version:        1
Release:        1%{?dist}
Summary:        Test

Group:          Test
License:        GPL
URL:            http://example.com 
Source0:        test-1.tar.gz 
BuildRoot:      %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-root-%(%{__id_u} -n)

#BuildRequires:  
#Requires:       

%description
This is a test to push files.

%prep
%setup -q

%build
#%configure
#make %{?_smp_mflags}

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
#make install DESTDIR=$RPM_BUILD_ROOT
install -m 0755 -d $RPM_BUILD_ROOT/opt/test

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files
%dir /opt/test
%defattr(-,root,root,-)
%doc
```

Any ideas on what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like the default GNU "`./configure`" script isn't there, so you can't use the default `%setup` macro in the spec file and will need a custom `%prep` section... [(One source)](http://www.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html) [(mirror)](http://ftp.rpm.org/max-rpm/s1-rpm-inside-scripts.html)

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to override the macro to stop it from executing `./configure`, but I put an empty config file in the root of the source and it allowed me to complete the build. Thanks for putting me on the right track.

Comment: Sorry - I should've looked closer! A well-known PITA "feature" of RPM is that you cannot comment out a macro like you did above. You have to put `#%%configure` or it only comments out the *first line* of the macro! (The first `%` escapes the second one.)

Comment: Confirmed I can build the rpm without the configure file now with the additional `%` in the comment, or by completely removing that line.  I was thinking my comment was effectively working.  Thanks!

Comment: One source link is down, [Fedora's wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/How_to_create_an_RPM_package#SPEC_file_sections_explained) has some helpful content but possibly not applicable to your packaging or target environment

Comment: @efx Thanks I added a mirror link too.